# Update DataGridView after marking the row of another - C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview

so I'm pretty new to coding and all this stuff so please, excuse me if this is a really stupid question, I've tried looking for it but haven't found anything that helped me.

I have two different DataGrids in my WinForm, one has infos on customers stored in it and the other different contact persons - both pulled from a database. 
Now I need to somehow get the second grid to update and only show the contacts that are related to the customer I have selected.

How would one go about this?

Help would very much be appreciated!

Comment: Presumably the "master" grid's data will contain an ID that is a foreign key on the "details" data. Figure out how to obtain the ID and do a query on the other data `WHERE ID = <that id>`.

Comment: Hi, Can you show us what you've already made? so we can see how we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it and am here to share it for future people who might have the same problem. This is how the function looks like, probably not the most pretty thing in the world, but it runs.

```
        public void RefreshContact(int customerID)
    {
        CustomerDBEntities db = new CustomerDBEntities();
        var contacts = db.Contacts;         

        dataGridView_Contacts.Rows.Clear();
        if (customerID != 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in db.Customers.Where(x => x.PKCustomer == customerID).First().Contact.ToList())
            {
                dataGridView_Contacts.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView_Contacts.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = item.PKContact;
                dataGridView_Contacts.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = item.Name;
                dataGridView_Contacts.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = item.Firstname;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is how I call for the function

```
        private void dataGridView_Customers_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerDBEntities db = new CustomerDBEntities();

        int customerID = (int)dataGridView_Customers.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;

        RefreshContacts(customerID);         
    }
```